# In Safari $_FILES doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, safari

I need to pass files and other data to ajax.
My code:

```js
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4'); // basic create pdf
var pdf = doc.output('blob');
var data = "";
if (flagSend == 1) {
  data = new FormData($("#sendInvoiceForm")[0]);
  data.append('flagSend', 1);
  var send_invoice_subject = $("#send_invoice_subject").val();
} else {
  data = new FormData();
  data.append('flagSend', 0);
}
data.append('data', pdf);
data.append('invoice_number', invoice_number);

 $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         data: data,
         processData: false,
         contentType: false,
         url: sJSUrlSavePdfInvoiceToServer,
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function (data) {

           }
         });
```

In my 'data' I pass a pdf file, and get it in php with `$_FILES['data']`.
It works well in Chrome,Firefox. But in Safari there is no `$_FILES['data']`, there is `$_REQUEST['data'] - [object Blob]`
So I can't upload  files in Safari:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["data"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
}
```

because there is no `$_FILES['data']` field.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Anybody know reason?

Comment: Firstly, `$_FILES` is a PHP construct, so the title is a little odd as Safari is irrelevant other than the data it sends. Secondly, you're using a very weird mix of jQuery and plain JS methods. I'd suggest sticking to one or the other to save confusion and make the code neater.

Comment: If you included JQuery to your project then why you use plain JavaScript ? I suggest use only JQuery

Comment: yes, will change it, but now the important is the problem with pass data in Safari

Comment: there is no $_FILES['data'] but there sholud be $_FILES['tmp_name']

Comment: there is not $_FILES['tmp_name']. All $_FILES array is empty in Safari